# mysql - SQL Error 1064

Tags: mysql

I tried to make a inner join query from these two tables but I get error every time.
customer table consist custId,custName,custPhone (custId is PK)
order table consist orderId,custId,orderDate (orderId is PK and custId is FK)
the error is :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order On customer.custId=order.custId LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

```
Select * From customer 
Inner Join order
On customer.custId=order.custId
```

Comment: Why are you joining anything? All the information you're selecting is in the first table.

Comment: try tp put bactracks **`** around **order** b/c it is a keyword

Comment: actually I need to collect custName, orderId and orderDate in the new table

Comment: try to put backtrack around order just.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Order` is a reserved word. Surround it with back quotes '`'

```
Select * From customer 
Inner Join `order`
On customer.custId=`order`.custId
```

Usage of reserved words as object names is not encouraged. Better change it to some other acceptable name like `orders` or `customer_orders`, or something else.

***Refer to***: [**MySQL Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)