# Update command with special SQL keywords in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying a update an entry in my SQL table which has a column name "from" in JDBC. 
Following is the SQL command that I am trying to execute:

```
    sql = "Update email_template set [from]="+"'"+3+"'"+" WHERE id="+idno;
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

However it shows the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[from]='Akshit' WHERE id=1' at line

Comment: what is your field name `from` Or `[from]` ?

Comment: why have you used `[from]` ? angle bracket ?

Comment: Then remove bracket and try with only `from`

Comment: I have used brackets because I read somewhere on stackoverflow that special SQL keywords like "from", "to" etc. need to be enclosed inside the brackets. However even without the brackets same error is being shown.

Comment: You have to put backticks instead of brackets

Comment: @user3425724: Use Prepared statements as well to bind values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql - SQL Error 1064](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422759/mysql-sql-error-1064)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's way of escaping column names is by using backticks:

```
sql = "Update email_template set `from`="+"'"+3+"'"+" WHERE id="+idno;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `java.sql.PreparedStatement` when handling SQL in Java. It can be used for batches and ensures malicious SQL is not injected as part of the SQL code.

This is how your code looks with a `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE `email_template` SET `from` = ? WHERE id = ?"); 
stmt.setInt(1, 3);
stmt.setInt(2, idno);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

If this is an operation you execute for many rows in one go, replace `stmt.executeUpdate()` with `stmt.addBatch()` (likely in some loop) and when you're ready to execute the batched updates you call `stmt.executeBatch()`.

Note that both `executeUpdate()` and `executeBatch()` return how many rows were affected; which is something you may want to validate after a commit.